# Div to take entire height of viewport, until scroll to next div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 5 div containers. I want to render the first div to be the entire height of the viewport. And on scroll, next div takes over entire height of viewport. How would I do this?

HTML Code:

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div id="first-container" >
            <p> hello </p>
    </div>

    <div id="second-container">
            <p> hello </p>
    </div>

    <div id="third-container">
            <p> hello </p>
    </div>

    <div id="four-container">
            <p> hello </p>
    </div>

    <div id="five-container">
        <p> hello </p>
    </div>

</div>
```

I found this simple CSS code. It works on the first div but then doesn't allow me to scroll to the next div.

```
#first-container{
    position: fixed !important;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
#second-container{
    background-image: url("blue-gradient.png");
}

#third-container{
    background-color: #A8CEFF;
}

#four-container{
    background-image: url("green-gradient.png");
}

#five-container{
    background-color: #394457;
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you are attempting to implement parallax scrolling right?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**
I've created a working fiddle of this: https://jsfiddle.net/zrgLahbx/1/ for demonstration

**How to set to 100% height of the viewport**
You can set the CSS  `height` property of the and `div` containers (`#first-container`, `#second-container` etc.) **to `100vh`.**

This `100vh` essentially means "set the height to `100%` of the `viewport` height (`vh`).

Like so:

```
#first-container {
    height: 100vh;
}
#second-container {
    height: 100vh;
}
... and so on ...
```

Personally, I would create a class for this:

```
.full-viewport-height {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Then apply this to each container:

```
<div class="full-viewport-height" >
        <p> hello </p>
</div>

<div class="full-viewport-height">
        <p> hello </p>
</div>
... and so on ...
```

---

**Furthermore**
I would also advise to set a fallback value (just above the `100vh`). Just in case the browser does not support `vh` - trust me I've seen this happen.

Like this:

```
.full-viewport-height {
    height: 800px;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

CSS goes top-down. So, in case the browser does not support `vh`, it will use the first value.

If the browser does support `vh`, the `vh` value will override the first `px` value, anyway.

*I would advise using `em`s if you can, instead of pixels.*

---

**Why what you've tried didn't work**
Setting the `position: fixed` property like you have done, along with the `top`, `bottom`... etc. will make that div appear `fixed` to 100% of the screen, and not move *whatsoever*.

Confusingly, you then set the position to `absolute`.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Set your `html`, and `body` to `height: 100%` and apply `height: 100%` to your sections. Like this:

## HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <section>
        Content 1
    </section>
    <section>
        Content 2
    </section>
    <section>
        Content 3
    </section>
    <section>
        Content 4
    </section>
    <section>
        Content 5
    </section>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

section {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it but I'm seeing all five contents on the same screen. (i.e. no scroll required to get to next section/content.

Answer (score 0):

Your position code will make any DIV take up the whole screen and ignore scrolling. You need to pull that code out into a class:

```
.active {
  position: fixed !important;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Then you can use the `vh` unit to specify that all child DIVs take up 100% of the viewport. Only the active one will ever be visible, but you need this to block off the space in the document and to calculate where they change.

```
.wrapper>div {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Next you need to tap into the `scroll` event and set the `active` class based on current positioning.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var containers = [...document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper > div')],
    heights = containers.map(c => $(c).height()),
    scrollTops = [],
    currentIdx = 0,
    nextUp = null,
    nextDown = null;
  
  heights.forEach( (h,i) => scrollTops.push(h + scrollTops[i-1] || 0) );
  
  setCurrentIdx(0);
  
  function setCurrentIdx(idx){
    
    if (containers[currentIdx])
      containers[currentIdx].classList.remove('active');
    
    currentIdx = idx;
    containers[currentIdx].classList.add('active');
    
    nextUp = ( idx === 0 ? null : scrollTops[currentIdx]  );
    nextDown = ( idx === scrollTops.length - 1 ? null : scrollTops[currentIdx + 1] );
  }
  function move(direction){
    var newIdx = currentIdx + (direction === 'up' ? -1 : 1);
    
    if (newIdx < 0 || newIdx >= containers.length)
      return;
      
    setCurrentIdx(newIdx);
  }

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

    console.log(nextUp, '<--', currentScroll, '-->', nextDown);
    
    if (nextDown && currentScroll > nextDown) 
      move('down');
    
    if (nextUp && currentScroll <= nextUp) 
      move('up');
    
  });
  
}());
```

```css
.wrapper>div {
  height: 100vh;
}
.wrapper{
  margin-bottom:100vh;
}
#first-container {
  background-color: gray;
}
#second-container {
  background-color: blue;
  ;
}
#third-container {
  background-color: #A8CEFF;
}
#four-container {
  background-color: green;
}
#five-container {
  background-color: #394457;
}
.active {
  position: fixed !important;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

  <div id="first-container" class="active">
    <p>hello 1</p>
  </div>

  <div id="second-container">
    <p>hello 2</p>
  </div>

  <div id="third-container">
    <p>hello 3</p>
  </div>

  <div id="four-container">
    <p>hello 4</p>
  </div>

  <div id="five-container">
    <p>hello 5</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: The working snippet looks great! I don't know why this isn't working for me. My console is givine me an error : Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined